# Angular2, cannot find module 'app/models/user' error

Tags: node.js, angular, frameworks

I was trying the example on 
https://sniederm.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/tutorial-ng2-rest-service/
and in step 2, in "user.service.ts" file I am getting " cannot find module 'app/models/user' " error on the

```
import { User } from "app/models/user";
```

line. I tried couple of things that I can find on web, such as replacing the "app" with "." in "app/models/user" but it did not work.

In the tutorial it says "*we will create a class User and place it in a file called user.ts within the „to-be-created“ subfolder app/models.*"
I am new to angular so at first I created this folder manually (right click->new folder) but then after I get the error, I created models folder with **ng generate module models** prompt. But still I get the error. The user.ts file is in models folder. Can somebody help me with this, please?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Depending on the TypeScript file configuration, the root path may be different than the configuration the tutorial used. You may have success with `"src/app/models/user"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your files structure is as below:

```
|app
 |models
  |user.ts
 |services
  |user.service.ts
```

Your import should be:

```
import { User } from "../models/user";
```

Answer (score 0):

You Lost file name and you add folder name without file name. Add path with file name "/filename"

example:

```
import {Product} from '../Model/Product.model'
```